# Java: How to remove anonymous ActionListeners?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am creating a quiz for school. There are several buttons for the questions which, when pressed, display the new question and create 4 different `ActionListeners` for the buttons of the 4 answers.
Now I need to remove the 4 `ActionListeners` after one button was pressed.
I am able to remove the `ActionListener` from the button itself, but I want to remove the other 3 `ActionListeners` as well.

Every new `ActionListener` looks like this:

```
btAnswer1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            lResult.setForeground(Color.red);
            lResult.setText("Wrong Answer :(");
            // The team is changed.
            if (aktTeam == 1)
            {
                aktTeam = 2;
                lAktTeam.setText("Team 2");
            }
            else
            {
                 aktTeam = 1;
                lAktTeam.setText("Team 1");
            }
            // Here, this ActionListener is removed. But the others should
            // be removed too.
            btAntwort1.removeActionListener(this);
        }
    });
```

I hope somebody can help. :)

**Edit: Solved by davidxxx. Thanks!**

Comment: Is this `awt`????

Comment: Save the references of the newly created `ActionListener`s (in an array for instance) and then reuse those references to remove them all later.

Comment: Do you have reference to the component that contains all the buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In your example you don't remove the `ActionListener` from the same btn on the which one you have added the listener:

You add it to `btAnswer1`:

```
btAnswer1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()...
```

But you remove it from `btAntwort1`:

```
btAntwort1.removeActionListener(this);
```

So, it should not work.

> Now I need to remove the 4 ActionListeners after one button was
>   pressed.

2) If removing all the `ActionListener`s associated to the Button is valid in our use case, you can do :

```
for( ActionListener listener : btAntwort1.getActionListeners() ) {
        btAntwort1.removeActionListener(listener);
 }
```

Otherwise if you don't want to remove all the `ActionListener`s associated to the button, you should not inline the anonymous `ActionListener` instances in order to keep a reference on them when you want to remove them from the button.

For example do that :

```
    ActionListener actionListenerOne = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             ...
        }
    };

    ActionListener actionListenerTwo = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             ...
        }
    };
```

Now you have for example two references on the `ActionListener` instances you may add to the button.

So you may do :

```
JButton button = ...;
button.addActionListener(actionListenerOne);
button.addActionListener(actionListenerTwo);
```

and later :

```
button.removeActionListener(actionListenerOne);
button.removeActionListener(actionListenerTwo);
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is looking for :)

Comment: @GhostCat Hello, thanks :) I hope you are fine. Let met some minutes and I will tell you my mind.

Comment: @GhostCat, the question is very clear. I note only that it misses probably code example to illustrate and to give a way to people to test their answer.

Comment: Well, the simple# clean answer is to use bean validation - but that requires me to get clearance for one of the validation framework libraries.

Comment: @GhostCat  And is it a problem ? From a practical point of view, It stays better than reinventing the wheel or twisting Gson, that will probably result to unconventional code and may provoke side effect in new Gson updates.

Comment: I know. That's why I said "From a practical point of view".  And in some companies, more delay than in others.